# Nativescript - ChangeDetectorRef does not exist in my component

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-changedetection

I try to automatically update an array used in a Listview. To do that, I use ChangeDetectorRef like this :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "register",
    templateUrl: "./register.html",
    styleUrls: ["./register.css"],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

@Input regis = Array<string>;

constructor(cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}

ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

However, I get this error :

> error TS2339: Property 'cdr' does not exist on type 'RegisterComponent'.

Could someone explain me what I misunderstood ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a local variable within constructor until you add a accessor like public / private.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "register",
    templateUrl: "./register.html",
    styleUrls: ["./register.css"],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

@Input regis = Array<string>;

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}

ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, you are simply accepting a parameter. If you wish this to be a short-hand property definition, you must actively provide a visibility.

```
constructor(public cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}
constructor(protected cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

Otherwise, `cdr` is only available within the constructor itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)